# Developing apps for IPad

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch, ipad

Just a quick question. If I learn how to develop apps for IPhone using XCode, Cocoa, Objective-C etc. (and probably the book Programming in Objective-C by Stephen Kochan) will I be able to start developing apps for ipad right away? or there are some fundamental differences besides their size ? Thanks.

Comment: You can't use Cocoa to develop iPhone or iPad apps. You must use Cocoa Touch.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

iPad Development is done under the same language/framework (Objective C and Cocoa Touch) and you can create joint iPhone/iPad Projects so the answer is yes.

There are a few more UI components on the iPad than on the iPhone such as Popovers and Split Views but once you get a fundamental understanding on either device you'll easily be able to adapt.

Comment: You can't use Cocoa to develop iPhone or iPad apps. You must use Cocoa Touch.

Comment: Absolutely correct and i've edited the original post to clear up the misunderstanding.

Answer (score 2):

The Human Interface Guides are slightly different because you have different controls available to you. But the code style is the same.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I marked the other answer since it was a bit more detailed.